# Какой API лучше использовать (С++)

Tags: c++, api

Имею задачу: написать программу, страющую маршрут  БПЛ (беспилотника) по заданным точкам (долгота и широта). Причем лучше, если бы все это работало офлайн и желательно на чистом C++. Так вот назрел вопрос, какой API лучше использовать для карты? Ну тоесть, с помощью чего лучше отображать карту и маршрут?

Comment: @Abyx исправил. Карт, конечно же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, что нужно, то `http api` от гугла можно использовать через `curl`, а графику рисовать с помощью `Qt` (Если брать `Qt`, то `curl` не нужен, в `Qt` есть `QtNetwork`)